# Issue returning <a> link excluding mailto links

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack, linq-to-objects

I am making use of the HTML Agility Pack to define a function that returns the links on a web page. The issue is that it returns all links including mailto.

Later in the program, when the links are processed the mailto links break. I'm trying to eliminate their inclusion in the function output list of _links

My function is defined as:

```
var linkNodes = _htmlDocument.Value.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
if (linkNodes == null)
    return Enumerable.Empty<Link>();

var links = new List<Link>();
foreach (var linkNode in linkNodes)
{
    var href = linkNode.GetAttributeValue("href", "#");
    if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(href, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        continue;

    var url = href.ToAbsoluteUri(Url);
    var follow = linkNode.GetAttributeValue("rel", "follow");

    links.Add(new Link(Url, url, linkNode.InnerText, follow));
}

_links = links;
```

My LINQ that almost worked (worked in getting rid of mailto, but returned strings instead of the nodes that match the fighters used):

```
var linkNodes = _htmlDocument.Value.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                        .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
                        .Where(href => !href.StartsWith("mailto:")) // skip emails, find only url links
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: try change your linq to  `htmlDocument.Value.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").Where(a => !a.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("mailto:")).ToList();`

Comment: in one of the iterations there is an error: {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}

Comment: try to use null conditional operator if you have c#6.  `htmlDocument.Value.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").Where(a => !a.Attributes["href"].Value?.StartsWith("mailto:") ?? false).ToList();`

Comment: i think i see it but an explanation on where i went wrong would help, and i can mark an answer accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About Select and Where:**

According to  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Linq `Select` will convert your collection into new form based on items of that collection. Here is the simple example.

```
IEnumerable<int> collectionOfInt = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
IEnumerable<string> collectionOfString = collectionOfInt.Select(i => i.ToString());
IEnumerable<int> lengthOfStrings = collectionOfString.Select(str => str.Length);
```

First you have a collection of `int` from 0 to 9. As you can see Select returns a new collection of string but based on items of `collectionOfInt` so you have strings from `"0","1",...,"9"`. Note that the execution of Select is deferred so have to use `ToList` to actually execute that query.

The same thing when you perform `Select` on `collectionOfString`. As you can see you loose the actual string and you will get Length of those strings instead (`1,1,...,1`).

Now your Linq

```
var linkNodes = _htmlDocument.Value.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                    .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
                    .Where(href => !href.StartsWith("mailto:"))
                    .ToList();
```

The same thing happens here. you have a collection of Nodes but `Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)` will actually turn your Nodes into collection of string and you will loose actual Nodes.

```
.Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value) // Changes main collection into values
.Where(href => !href.StartsWith("mailto:")) // searches on values not main collection thus returns values again.
```

So you have to put it all in `Where` part. because `Where` does not change collection type. It only choose elements from the collection when a condition is true on that element.

According to my explanations `href` in previous query is `a.Attributes["href"].Value`. So in order to not loose original elements just wrap `a.Attributes["href"].Value` inside `href` So you will have

```
.Where(node => !node.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("mailto:")) // searches on nodes collection thus returns nodes
```

**About the Null exception part:**

`Where` Linq query will not search on items that are null. so whenever `href` or `a.Attributes["href"].Value` in previous query is null it will just skip that item without selecting it.

After you inline `Select` into `Where` now where only checks on nullability of `node` not execution of function `!node.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("mailto:")`.

Basically because there is possibility of null for `Value` you will get exception on `StartsWith("mailto:")` which can not handle null.

In C#6 you can fix this with mixing [`null conditional`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) and [`Null-coalescing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operators.

```
htmlDocument.Value.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
    .Where(node => !node.Attributes["href"].Value?.StartsWith("mailto:") ?? false).ToList();
```

if value of `Value?.` is null it will not continue to execute `StartsWith("mailto:")` and instead returns null directly.

Because return type of `?.` is `nullable bool` then `?? false` will return false when ever left side of operator is null.